# How can I print only values in perl, result returned from mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, perl

**Script**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use MongoDB;
use Data::Printer;
my $client = MongoDB::MongoClient->new();
my $db   = $client->get_database('students');
my $grades = $db->get_collection('grades');
my $stu = $grades->find->fields({student_id=>1,_id=>0});
while (my $row = $stu->next){
p($row);
}
```

**Output:**

```
\ {
    student_id   198
}
\ {
    student_id   199
}
```

**Intended Output:**

```
198
199
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Data::Printer](http://p3rl.org/Data::Printer) is meant for *human-readable data inspection*. It prints to `STDOUT`. That's for debugging and looking at data structures during development.

If you want to actually access and print the data to the screen, you need to access it yourself. Data::Printer helps you do this, because it tells you what your data structure looks like.

To print your `student_id`s (the values of those keys), just `print` them.

```
while (my $row = $stu->next){
    print "$row->{student_id}\n";
}
```

That's it. Consider using [`say`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html) instead as it contains the `\n` already.

```
say $row->{student_id};
```

You need to do `use feature 'say';` or [use a version pragma](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) that includes it to do that.